# ASP.net MVC Model for clothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm trying to create a full MVC web app for a fake clothing website just for experience (first time using this framework). 
I created a class in models named ClothingItem to manage each item of clothing being sold. 
In this class I would like to store information such as: 
- brand (seller will only be selling a limited range of clothing e.g. tommy/ralph and occasionally other random pieces) 
- type of clothing (e.g. polo/tee/jacket)
- color/pattern
- size (XL+, XL, L, M, S, XS)
- price

It is clear to me that I should use a decimal type for the price, however, I am unsure as to what type I should be using for brand, type, color, and size.

I considered using enums (bearing in mind I would like the user to be able to filter clothing items by brand/size/type) for these but I am unsure as to whether I should do this or just use a string to store the type, I would like to know what I should be using, whether I am along the right track, or if I'm just taking a completely wrong approach to this? Thanks in advance

example of enum:

```
Public enum Brand {
   TommyHilfiger = 1,
   RalphLauren,
   Adidas,
   Nike
}
```

Comment: An enum sounds entirely suitable for this use case.

Comment: And `enum` would not be appropriate for `Brands` as Brands may change over time (new ones added etc) - although it is probably appropriate for the `Sizes` which are unlikely to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enums can be useful if your are just testing and you want to learn ASP.NET MVC

But for a real application it will be a bad solution, why ?
Imagine that you have to add a new Brand to your application, for example : **Lacoste**
You will need to open you source code and add the new value to your enum and recompile the application.
A better approach (but with more work to do) is to manage your brands via a table in database that will be mapped to a class in your model.

```
public class Brand {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

For a filter, you will need to request the list of all brands as string and show them in Dropdown for example.

I'm sure there is many other solutions